# Is there any way to print all selected dates in date-range-picker instead of it first and last dates in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to print all selected dates in date range picker, is there anyway to do it?

here is my code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:date_range_picker/date_range_picker.dart' as DateRagePicker;

    class TryCalendar extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _TryCalendarState createState() => _TryCalendarState();
    }

    class _TryCalendarState extends State<TryCalendar> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(

          ),
          body: new MaterialButton(
          color: Color(0xFFED7D31),
          onPressed: () async {
          final List<DateTime> picked = await DateRagePicker.showDatePicker(
              context: context,
              initialFirstDate: new DateTime.now(),
              initialLastDate: (new DateTime.now()).add(new Duration(days: 7)),
              firstDate: new DateTime(2015),
              lastDate: new DateTime(2020)
          );
          if (picked != null && picked.length == 2) {
              print(picked);
          }
        },
        child: new Text("Pick date range")
          )
        );
      }
    }
```

I need to print all selected dates instead of first and last selected dates. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<DateTime> getDaysInBeteween(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
  List<DateTime> days = [];
    for (int i = 0; i <= endDate.difference(startDate).inDays; i++) {
      days.add(startDate.add(Duration(days: i)));
    }
  return days;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

picked is list of DateTime , so you should iterate every date in list then print

```
if (picked != null && picked.length >= 2) {
   picked.forEach((date) {
     print(date.toString());
   });
}
```

Comment: It only print first and last dates not the whole selected dates. I need to print all the selected dates between the two selected first and last dates. Thank you!